# R Imagemagick "skips" annotations and turns monochrome

Tags: r, imagemagick

I'm working on a composite graph in R, for which I export a ggplot and then load it into magick for further annotations and compositing another graph. Since alignment is a lot of trial and error, I will keep a version with all "final" annotations and use a second image to play around with.

Usually, this works pretty well, but from time to time either or both of two errors will happen:

- The image turns into black/white (not even grayscale, just hard black/white)
- Some of the annotations are being "skipped", meaning they just don't show up in the preview

I have tested the second error, and the sequence of commands matters. All annotations until a certain point will be applied and all thereafter won't.

The only thing that reliably "fixes" the error is restarting the PC. Restarting the R session, clearing the cache, restarting Rstudio remain without effect. Once this error has occurred, it will keep persisting (rerunning the code will produce the exact same result) until a system reboot.

A simplified version of what my code does:

```
graph1 <- image_read(path1)
graph2 <- image_read(path2)
annotated_graph <- graph1 %>%  # creating a saved version so I don't have to run all of the code every time
  image_border(color='white', geometry = '2000x1000') %>%
  image_annotate("text1", size = 100, color = "black", location = "+1000+4000") %>%
  image_annotate("text2", size = 100, color = "black", location = "+2000+4000")
annotated_graph %>%  # opens current "experiment" state in viewer
  image_annotate("text3", size = 100, color = "black", location = "+3000+4000") %>%
  image_composite(image_scale(graph2, "1000"), offset = "+1000+1000")
```

To test if the viewer itself might be the problem, I have tested opening it in a browser (to no avail). I also tried opening it in the plot window with the code below, but it just shows the same error (in lower resolution):

```
tiff_file <- tempfile()
image_write(annotated_graph, path = tiff_file, format = 'tiff')
r <- raster::brick(tiff_file)
raster::plotRGB(r)
```

I thought this might be a memory issue, but according to task manager there's several gigabytes of free RAM.

I'd be really happy to resolve the issue altogether, but finding a way to restart whatever component needs to be restarted without rebooting the entire system would already be splendid!

My specs: Win10 on AMD64, R 4.0.2, magick 2.4.0